# TypeError: response.data is undefined Facebook api

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-like

I would like to use this tutorial: http://www.webtuts.info/webdevelopment/facebook-download-script-2/225/. And I only change the appId. And I get this error:

```
TypeError: response.data is undefined
[Break On This Error]   

...( response.data.length == 1 ) { //there should only be a single value inside "da...
```

Here is my code: http://pastebin.com/dz3LMWaP
Can anybody help me whats the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible to tell what is the problem since there could be many reasons - add this to your code right before the line in your post, it won't fix your problem but it'll give your more exact info that on what is the problem.

```
if (response.error) {
      console.log('Error - ' + response.error.message);
      return
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`response` does not contain a property `data` so when you try to get the length of it, Javascript throws an error.

You will want to examine `response` via `console.log()`.